# SSH can't send command

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

### Description

I first encountered this problem when I tried to use SCP to another computer over LAN, and get
`zsh:1: command not found: scp`
Now before anyone asks: **yes I have SSH installed**.
I can use ssh to log into the other computer just fine.
The problem is SCP, and `ssh [user@]hostname [command]` both result in `zsh:1: command not found: [command]`.

### Testing

I tried using SCP with localhost

```
systemctl start sshd.service
scp /home/user/asdf.log user@127.0.0.1:/home/user/test/asdf.log
...
zsh:1: command not found: scp
```

And then sending a command:

```
ssh user@127.0.0.1 ls
...
zsh:1: command not found: ls
```

`ssh user@127.0.0.1` works as expected.

I used the `-v` switch, and the info looked normal.
I tried switching to Bash instead of ZSH; same error.

Finally, I tried root login, and that worked

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 ls
...
Desktop
Documents
Music
...
```

#### SSH Config:

`~/.ssh/config`: nothing

```
#/etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitRootLogin yes # this is bad; for testing only
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
PrintMotd no #pam does that
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
```

Using Arch Linux with openssh 7.9p1

### TL;DR

It looks like the environment isn't getting set (not even PATH)
for SCP and single command SSH. But, for root login it is getting set properly.
Any ideas about this?

#### Update

It's something with my user shell config.
I added a new, blank user account, and using SCP into that worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

There was a line in my `~/.pam_environment` setting my path.
`PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/home/@{PAM_USER}/bin`
This for some reason puts /home/user/bin in my path 3 times, and adds an extra colon.
Why it does this, I'm not sure.
But setting my PATH in `~/.profile` instead, fixed the problem.

I guess, the bad PATH assignment was discarded by ssh, but not by my regular login.